# COUNT(*) in sub-query returning every row and not just those specific to the ID

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of tags and comments related to a each bookmark, via a sub-query. However, it's just counting all tags and comments.

```
SELECT
    bookmarks.bookmark_id,
    bookmarks.user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(bookmarks.creation, '%W %D of %M %Y, %H:%i') AS creation,
    DATE_FORMAT(bookmarks.modification, '%W %D of %M %Y, %H:%i') AS modification,
    bookmarks.url,
    bookmarks.title,
    bookmarks.snippet,
    bookmarks.status,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(tags.tag) AS tags
        FROM
            tags
        INNER JOIN
            bookmarks
        ON
            (tags.bookmark_id = bookmarks.bookmark_id)
        WHERE
            (tags.user_id = '1')
    ) AS tags,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(bookmarks_comments.comment) AS comments
        FROM
            bookmarks_comments
        INNER JOIN
            bookmarks
        ON
            (bookmarks_comments.bookmark_id = bookmarks.bookmark_id)
        WHERE
            (bookmarks_comments.user_id = '1')
    ) AS comments
FROM
    bookmarks
WHERE
    (bookmarks.user_id = '1')
GROUP BY bookmarks.bookmark_id
```

Maybe it's the lateness of the hour. I don't know. But I CANNOT figure this out. Any ideas?

Comment: Please stop using `GROUP BY` this way. It's not standard and will hurt you in the long run.

Comment: see here: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subqquery is doing a join, so it is not correlated to the outer query.  Here is what you want for the first one:

```
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(tags.tag) AS tags
    FROM
        tags
    where 
        (tags.bookmark_id = bookmarks.bookmark_id)
    and
        (tags.user_id = '1')
) AS tags,
```

Notice I removed the `join`.  Now, when SQL sees `bookmarks.bookmarks_id` it will go to the `bookmarks` table in the outer query.

And you have the same problem with `comments`.

Comment: just so you know, that query snippet isn't correct syntactically, but it is — on the whole — the correct idea. It should WHERE then AND, not ON then WHERE.

Comment: @WayneSmallman . . . I fixed it.  Also, assuming that `user_id` is an integer, you don't need to put the `1` in quotes.